# How to Replace only Part of the Variable using #define

Tags: c++

```
#define C_TX_ TX_
#define C_RX_ RX_

enum Test
{
        C_TX_MAC = 0x0100, // Pre-Processor should replace C_TX_ to TX_
        C_RX_MAC = 0x0101  // But Not Working.
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << TX_MAC; // HOW TO PRINT ?
    cout << RX_MAC; // HOW TO PRINT ?

    return true;

}
```

Comment: This: `C_TX_MAC` will be read as a single token. You cannot "stop" halfway. What's your bigger picture?

Comment: I have big variable name like C_ADDR_TX_MAC_DESTINATION_ADDRESS_FIELD_WORD_0_0 where i need to replace only C_ADDR_TX_ with TX_ only

Comment: Why not just use `C_ADDR_TX_…` in the code?

Comment: I suggest using a text editor to do the replacing

Answer (score 2):

The pre-processor only operates on strings that are entire tokens.  There would be chaos otherwise.

Try:

```
#define C_TX_MAC TX_MAC
#define C_RX_MAC RX_MAC
```

Comment: I have big variable name like C_ADDR_TX_MAC_DESTINATION_ADDRESS_FIELD_WORD_0_0 where i need to replace only C_ADDR_TX_ with TX_ only.

Comment: @mahesh: But what is the "need"? I'm sure there are other solutions.

Comment: Well, tough.  The pre-processor can't operate on substrings or things like `#define tf 4` would break every call to `printf()`. You have to use the entire token.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split a token with the pre-processor. You need to

```
#define C_RX_MAC RX_MAC
#define C_TX_MAC TX_MAC
```

(Of course there's ugly solutions such as adding a pre-pre-processing step:

```
sed s/C_ADDR_// x.cpp | g++ -x c++ -
```

But `sed` doesn't know about the context. It will replace strings e.g. `cout << "And C_ADDR_RX = "` with `cout << "And RX = "`.)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers the pre-processor uses the whitespace to work out where the token is defined, and cannot replace it 'part way through".  Perhaps you could try a "Find/Replace In Files" to rename the variables in your source code directly.  Visual Studio's Find and Replace function can be used to replace any occurences in any folders/subfolders, or if you don't run with the Microsoft there's some other programs like [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) that offer the same functionality.  Both also support Regular Expressions for better targeted find/replace queries

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor replaces tokens, and `C_TX_MAC` is a full token.

However, you can achieve this fairly easily with some macro concatenation:

```
#include <iostream>
#define foo(x) C_ ## x

enum Test
{
        C_TX_MAC = 0x0100, // Pre-Processor should replace C_TX_ to TX_
        C_RX_MAC = 0x0101  // But Not Working.
};

int main()
{
   std::cout << foo(TX_MAC) << ' ' << foo(RX_MAC) << '\n';
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def2e01b918a5182))

Easy. No need for `sed`, and no need for find-and-replace in your text editor.